# Which option do I have to modify to see more records without press `q`

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm connected remotly to my database server with cygwin in full screen.

When I query my database with

```
   select id, name from table limit 27;
```

I get 27 records and I can do a new query seeing the result of the previous query.

But, If I replace 27 by 28, I see 28 records in one screen with an `(End)` in reverse video.
If I want to do a new query, I have to press `q`.

I can't see the result of the previous query even if I use the scrollbar of my cygwin window.

Which option do I have to modify to increase this buffer ?

My psql client and database server version is 9.1.4 and they are installed on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn off (and on) the paging in `psql`:

```
\pset pager [on|off]
```

If you don't specify `on` or `off`, the command will toggle the setting.  (More on `\pset` in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html).)
In the shell, you can even set the pager you want to use:

```
PAGER=/usr/bin/less
```

If you start `psql` after this, `less` will be your pager.

Comment: Thank you. FYI, if you want to use it with `psql -c "sql query"`, you have to add "-P pager=off"  
Then you would have `psql -P pager=off -c query`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `less` is used as the pager, you can turn off this screen-clearing feature which indeed is annoying within psql. Use the `-X` option:

> ```
>   -X or --no-init
>           Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
>           strings to the terminal.  This is  sometimes  desirable  if  the
>           deinitialization  string does something unnecessary, like clear‐
>           ing the screen.
> ```

The option can be set as an environment variable in your `$HOME/.profile` init file:

```
LESS="-X"
export LESS
```